# SQL Data Compare - Can I randomize a column's value before moving the data over?

Tags: sql, redgate

I want to move some data from my prod database to my test database via SQL Data Compare. I would like to set this up to run regularly. However I do not want to move email addresses from prod into test, but I need a fake email in that column. Is there a way to put fake data in during the move, but use the real data for the rest of the columns?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't modify the data as part of a Data Compare run. The tool is really simple & straightforward, compare two things, spot the differences, move the differences. That's it.

You could look to a tool [like Data Masker](https://www.red-gate.com/products/data-masker/) to modify the data after Compare has moved it. Other mechanisms are also available before or after Data Compare is used, but Data Compare just doesn't do that kind of work.